# If A is unitary and $\det (A^H) = \det(A^*)$ and $\det(A) \det(A^*) = \det(A)^2$ Why can't I say that $\det(A^H) = \pm\det(A)$

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant, unitary-matrices, hermitian-matrices

this came up on a Homework I have. 
I had to prove that the absolute value of the determinant of a Unitary Matrix is 1.

So because $\det (A^H) = \det(A^*)$ 
and $\det(A) \det(A^*) = \det(A)^2$
as well as that for a Unitary Matrix $A*A^H=I$ that $\det(A^*) = \pm \det(A)$

This was my wrong step.

And the correct one confuses me even more.
It's $\det (A^H) = \det(conjugate(A))$

$\det(A) \det(A^*) = \det(A)^2$ then

$\det(A)^2 = I = 1$

Which looks like it's saying the same to me. Thank you to anyone who may shed some light on this for me, it's much appreciated.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo I will change, I'm sorry I wasn't aware of this notation, only the bar above A, which I didn't know how to do.

Comment: If you prefer the bar, use `\bar{A}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The product of a complex number with its conjugate is equal to its squared modulus. Therefore $\det(A)\det(\overline{A})$ in general is equal to $|\det(A)|^2$, not $\det(A)^2$.

Comment: Hello, thank you, this probably is my problem. I thought that this would turn out the same? I'm sorry I'm super confused now.

Comment: @oliver Huh, how?

Comment: not the same, but just a difference of +/- is | det(A) | ^2 not the square of the absolute value of det(A) ? @user1551 thank you for taking the time!

Comment: @oliver Are you suggesting that $|z|^2=1$ implies $\overline{z}=\pm z$?!

Comment: Thank you! I see my mistake now, and yes, I was not seeing the difference before.